# Using dynamic Kubernetes annotations in Terraform based on a variable

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am trying to add a set of annotations based on a variable value.

So far, I am trying to add something like:

```
annotations = merge({
   annotation1 = value
   annotation2 = value
   try(var.omitAnnotations == false) == null ? {} : {
       annotation3 = value
       annotation4 = value
   }})
```

However, this doesn't appear to be working as expected, and in fact, the annotations are always added, regardless of the value in var.addAnnotations

How can I get this logic working, so that annotation3 & annotation4 are only added when var.addAnnotations is true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it always adds `annotation3` and `annotation4` - it means that `try(var.omitAnnotations == false) == null` ---- this is never `null`. It's easy to see, given `var.omitAnnotations == false` is either `true` or `false`, and it is never `null`.

Comment: Unless you haven't copied everything, I think the way you are using try is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest moving any expressions that are too complicated to a local variable, because of visibility:

```
locals {
   annotations = var.omitAnnotations ? {} : {
       "annotation3" = "value3"
       "annotation4" = "value4"
   }
   add_annotations = try(local.annotations, null)
}
```

What this will do is set the `local.annotations` variable to an empty map if `var.omitAnnotations` is `true` or to a map with annotations `annotation3` and `annotation4` defined if `var.omitAnnotations` is `false`. The local variable `add_annotations` will then have the value assigned based on using the `try` built-in function [1]. In the last step, you would just do the following:

```
annotations = merge(
  {
   "annotation1" = "value1"
   "annotation2" = "value2"
   },
   local.add_annotations
)
```

Comment: Hey Marko, is the `try` necessary? Couldn't OP just use `local.annotations`?

Comment: It probably could and that's a good point.

Comment: Altough, I am not sure if annotations can accept an empty map or it has to be null.

Comment: I did try with the `kubernetes_namespace_v1` resource and does support an empty map.